# Unable to run Tomcat 7 as service inside container on CoreOS

Tags: tomcat7, docker, coreos

I am trying to setup tomcat 7 on Digital Ocean CoreOS machine but facing some problem, not sure how to solve them. I am following below tutorial provided by the Digital Ocean to setup Apache.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-and-run-a-service-on-a-coreos-cluster

I created docker container and run it using following command.

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

I was successfully able to install tomcat 7 by using below commands. (I followed this tutorial to setup tomcat 7 within the docker container: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get)

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Then I can created service unit file named as tomcat@.service

```
[Unit] 
Description=Tomcat 7 web server service 
After=etcd.service After=docker.service     
Requires=tomcat-discovery@%i.service

[Service] 
TimeoutStartSec=0 KillMode=none 
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment 
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill tomcat%i 
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm tomcat%i 
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull attacomsian/tomcat 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run –name tomcat%i -p ${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}:%i:8080 attacomsian/tomcat `service tomcat7 start` -D FOREGROUND 
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop tomcat%i

[X-Fleet]
X-Conflicts=tomcat@*.service
```

Then I created tomcat-discovery@.service to register service states with Etcd as below

```
[Unit] 
Description=Announce Tomcat@%i service 
BindsTo=tomcat@%i.service

[Service] 
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c “while true; do etcdctl set /announce/services/tomcat%i ${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}:%i –ttl 60; sleep 45; done” 
ExecStop=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm /announce/services/tomcat%i

[X-Fleet]
X-ConditionMachineOf=tomcat@%i.service
```

I submitted and loaded files to Fleet as below

```
fleetctl submit tomcat@.service tomcat-discovery@.service

fleetctl load tomcat@8080.service

fleetctl load tomcat-discovery@8080.service
```

Everything worked fine so far. I did not see any error. But when I tried to run the service as below

```
fleetctl start tomcat@8080.service
```

But it did not started. I can see it is appearing as dead.

I am new to CoreOS and still learning. I am managing servers at Digital Ocean and I quite about it quite well. I googled about this issue but did not found any help. I personally think following line is actually causing the trouble.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run –name tomcat%i -p ${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}:%i:8080 attacomsian/tomcat `service tomcat7 start` -D FOREGROUND
```

I would really appreciate any kind help to get this up.

Many Thanks

Attacomsian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going so suggest you take a look at what others have done and then discovered you have posted a similar question on the [Docker Hub registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tutum/tomcat/).

Did you take a look at the Docker file used by the tutum/tomcat image?

- https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-tomcat/blob/master/7.0/Dockerfile
- https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-tomcat/blob/master/7.0/run.sh

It runs a script called "run.sh" that runs tomcat in the foreground.

The thing that is tricky to understand is that Docker is not a virtual machine and therefore does not have any services running. You must run the docker processes explicitly or setup a process manager like runit or supervisord.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to figure out that it was tomcat which was not started inside container. I tried to run the tomcat inside container just to test and it gave me following error 

Address already in use <null>:8080

Then I tried to run it on another ports, but every time I got same error: Address already in use. That is really strange for me. Do you have any idea why is it so?

Comment: When you create a docker container, it isn't removed by default when the container stops running. This means that the port is still bound to the container, which is why you can't reuse it. Removing the container will free up the port again.

Comment: Ok Rob. I stopped and removed all existing container manually but when I tried to run the it again using docker run --name tomcat88 -p ${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}:8888:9999 attacomsian/tomcat service tomcat7 start -D FOREGROUND, it again failed. I think the issue is in the tomcat7 packages I installed.